# Deserializing Protected constructed object from json

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, json.net, deserialization

I'm using newton's json.net serializer. When deserializing the json to 'TheFox'; it enters to the protected ctor and gets the default property values. But not the property values in the json string. Can i solve this problem without using dto or any other mapper framework?

```
class TheFox
    {

    string _Id;
    string _Name;

    protected TheFox()
    {
        _Id = "Default Id";
        _Name = "Default Name";
    }

    public TheFox(string id, string name) : this()
    {
        _Name = name;
        _Id = id;
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
    }
}
```

That's the test:

```
        var fox = new TheFox("FoxId", "FoxTail");
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fox);
        Console.WriteLine(json);

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings ()
        {
            ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor
        };

        var returned = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TheFox> (json, settings);

        Assert.IsTrue (returned.Id != "Default Id");
        Assert.IsTrue (returned.Name != "Default Name");
```

Comment: Strange that so many deserializers don't support parametrized constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked the source of in json.net  and there's no way for now. Because if the given property is readonly it skips the setting the value stage. may be needs an internal field populator feature.

```
private void SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonReader reader, object target)
    {
      // bla.. bla.. bla..
      if (!property.Writable && !useExistingValue)
      {
        reader.Skip();
        return;
      }
```

That method is a bad one, it needs an instantiated object to fill but it works.

```
var a = new TheFox("x", "y");
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
Console.WriteLine(json);

var returned = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, new TheFox("q", "a")); 

Assert.That(a.Id, Is.EqualTo(returned.Id));
Assert.That(a.Name, Is.EqualTo(returned.Name));
```

Comment: Are you strongly opposed to using protected or even private setters for those properties? It would help you if used with [JsonProperty] annotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class TheFox
    {
      string _Id;
      string _Name;

      protected TheFox() : this("Default Id", "Default Name")

      public TheFox(string id, string name)
      {
        _Name = name;
        _Id = id;
      }

      public string Id
      {
        get { return _Id; }
      }

      public string Name
      {
        get { return _Name; }
      }
}
```

This should allow for the same usage but offers comparability with newton.

Comment: the two of your constructor call themselves recursively. I removed parameterful ctor and run the test. Nope, result not changed. still the default values.

Comment: Sorry, that's the last time i try and write code on the iPad! Fixed the errors.

Answer (score -2):

Your class is not appropriate for client side operation. You need to use DataContractAttribute to the class and DataMemberAttribute attribute to the members you want to serialize.

Comment: i am just deserializing my object with a framework. i have no business with wcf.